# Get a KeyError in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to call a function from a different module as below:

```
module1 - func1: returns a dataframe

module1 - func2(p_df_in_fromfunc1)
```

function 2:

```py
for i in range(0,len(p_df_in_fromfunc1):
    # Trying to retrieve row values of individual columns and assign to variables
    v_tmp = p_df_in_fromfunc1.loc[i,"Col1"]
```

When trying to run the above code, I get the error:

> KeyError 0

Could the issue be because I don't have a zero numbered row?

Comment: I edited your post, including your code snippet, whch was not valid python. Please check it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select rows from a DataFrame based on column values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/how-to-select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-column-values)

Comment: I assume that is pretty much due to your index of dataframe. Is your data indexed with raw incremental row numbers? If so, did you do any filtering on data (func1 perhaps) so that the ith location is not present in the df.

Comment: @null - Yes, I found the problem. My index does not have zero, since I had created a subset of my original dataframe, which is what is used now to do my calculations. How can I resolve the issue?

Comment: I found the issue and fixed it (reset the index) per null's suggestion. Is their a better solution, when we have to take a subset of a dataframe and pass it to a function for performing calculations?

Comment: try `df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)` assuming your dateframe variable is `df`.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing much of you're code, well my guess is, for positional indexing try using iloc instead of loc, if you're interesed in going index-wise.
Something like:

```
v_tmp = p_df_in_fromfunc1.iloc[i,"Col1"]
```

Answer (score 0):

For retrieving a row for specific columns do:

```py
columns = ['Col1', 'Col2']
df[columns].iloc[index]
```

If you only want one column, you can simplify it to: `df['Col1'].iloc(index)`

As per your comment, you do not need to reset the index, you can iterate over the values of your index array: `df.index`

Comment: I want multiple columns, not just one. The above was just an example.

Comment: Note that columns is an array, you can have the label of multiple columns. Updated the answer to make it more clear

Answer (score 0):

You may have a missed to close the quote in the loc function after Col1 ?

```
v_tmp = p_df_in_fromfunc1.loc[i,"Col1"]
```